# Alert view frame is distorted

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uialertview

I have an alert view having frame size  (10, 30, 300, 300).I have a text field also inside it.
Frame of text field is (20, 125, 200, 50) with respect to alert view. My app is in both mode landscape as well as in portrait. It works fine with portrait but wont work in landscape mode. its height automatically decreased and text field overlapped "OK" and "cancel" button.

How can I manage frame of text field and alert view in both mode?

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to have the following method to allow input fields in an alert view, instead of explicitly adding a `UITextField`. This would also prevent the distortion when switching orientations,

```
[yourAlertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
```

And you can access the text from this input field as follows,

```
NSString *alertViewInputString = [[yourAlertView textFieldAtIndex: 0] text];
```

Go through the docs for other available input options in `UIAlertView`

Comment: My app is for ios4.3 users also. So I can't use this.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like it is a custom alert view? It seems like the subviews for the alert view have some auto resizing options enabled which you might not want enabled.  If you have laid it all out in the .xib file you might want to look at the following option for all of the views:

[image]

If it is all programatic, make sure to set the correct autoresizing mask. For example:

```
 view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

Comment: I have tried it but dint help me. I have also tried [alertView autoSizesSubViews:YES] but condition still remain same.